# Did Aryan race ever existed?

Tags: ancient-history

Did Aryans ever existed? or is this Aryan race thing a myth? People in general think that Aryans should be blonde with blue eyes, to what extent is this true? What is the Y-chromosome and mt-chromosome DNA of Aryan race?

Comment: Too broad, and will create many opinionated debates. Definition too wide, and conversely ideas of blond/blue-eyed too narrow. Also not clear about "what is Y-chromosome and mt-chromosome DNA".

Comment: I disagree with the on hold decision. If "Aryan" is/was a race, then the answer is yes, no opinion needed. If it isn't, then no. If opinions are needed to answer this question, then doesn't that mean the answer to the question is no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you want to call "Aryan race". The "Aryans" you're thinking of who are "blonde with blue eyes", **is a white supremacist fantasy.**

The archaic ethnolinguistic classification of "Aryans" were the native speakers of the [Proto-Indo-European language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language), and their modern descendents. **They are called the** [**Proto-Indo-Europeans**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-Europeans) and they existed. The modern speakers of the Indo-European languages are however not one "race".

Another similarly archaic classification of "**Aryans" were the** [**Proto-Indo-Iranians peoples**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Iranians). This name was derived from their endonym `Arya` (i.e. it was their ethnic self-designation). Their descendents are collectively known as the **Indo-Iranians,** which has sometimes inherited the "Aryan" designation. It includes the modern [Iranians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_people), the [Indo-Aryans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Aryans), and the [Nuristani people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuristani_people).

**The only current "Aryans" are the** [**Indo-Aryans peoples**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Aryan_peoples), speakers of the Indic branch of the [Indo-Iranian family of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Iranian_languages). They look like this:

[image]

It being tainted by Nazi/white supremacist uses notwithstanding, speaking of an "Aryan race" is still almost certainly rubbish. The modern Iranic peoples reached an Iran populated by ancient peoples such as the [Mannaeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannaeans) and the [Elamites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elam). When the Indo-Aryans migrated to India, they encountered native Dravidian peoples.

Their modern descendents might an Indo-Iranian language, but they are a mix of different lineages just like everyone else.

Comment: Agaian, perfect. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.